# Python creating binary tree with list of the strings in the leafs and list of strings in the childs

Tags: python, list, tree, binary-tree, decision-tree

I need help creating a binary tree using two lists 
one that represents the leaves in the tree and one that represents the
internal nodes in the tree,

input:

```
leafs= ['dead','healthy','cold','influenza']
childs_in_tree= ['cough','sneezing','fever']
```

output: ( Just the root tree like this not print it as in this way )

```
                                      cough
                       /                            \ 
                   sneezing                        sneezing
                /       \                          /       \ 
             fever         fever               fever         fever
          /    \            /     \          /    \           /     \
       dead   cold   influenza   cold      dead   influenza cold   healthy
```

Doesn't need to print this just the to return the root like this but not to print this shape just the nodes like this need to be..

My try was but not working for me:

```
 def buildtree(childs_in_tree,leafs):

    if len(leafs)==0:
        return Node(childs_in_tree[0])
    else:
        left=buildtree(childs_in_tree+[leafs[0]],leafs[1:])
        right=buildtree(childs_in_tree,leafs[1:])
        root=Node(childs_in_tree[0],right,left)
        return root
```

The class of the node im using:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data="", pos=None, neg=None):
       self.data = data
       self.positive_child = pos
       self.negative_child = neg
```

if anything is unclear don't hesitate to ask thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to build a tree level by levels? Childs is incorrect, you mean internal nodes. Also, leafs is incorrect, you mean leaves/terminal nodes.

Comment: Stop asking the same question you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054654/python-checking-paths-to-leaf-in-binary-tree-python-giving-data-in-the-leaf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061939/building-a-decision-tree-from-two-lists

Comment: @coldspeed Yeah internal nodes, and leaves that what i meant but my english is not that good sorry,  I have edited the question to make it more clear in the start thanks for your comment.

Comment: @DanielGee Its not the same question at that one ( checking paths ..) read it good this one is different.